# Clicking a cancel button and the collapse attribute stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following button and div:

```
<button id="button2" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseGroupTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseGroupTwo">
    <span style="float: left" id="span2a">Add New User</span>
    <span id="span2" class="glyphicon-plus" style="float: right; font-weight: bold"> 
    </span>
</button>

<div id="collapseGroupTwo" class="collapse">
    //snip
</div>

<script>
    $('#button2').click(function () {
        $('#span2').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus")
    })
</script>
```

When the user clicks 'Cancel' on cancelUpdateUser, the following JS runs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cancelUpdateUser').click(function () {
            $('#button3').hide();
            $('#collapseGroupThree').hide();
            $('#button2').show();

            document.getElementById("updateUserForm").reset();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Which should hide collapseGroupThree and button3 and show button2 and allow the click of button2 to expand its accompanying collapseGroupTwo. However, after button2 is brought back by the click event, when I click button2 collapseGroupTwo doesn't expand. Do I need to further toggle the collapse attribute on collapseGroupTwo?

Comment: Can you post the code for the click listener of #button2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click event for button 2 is not doing anything to show your second group...

```
$('#button2').click(function () {
    $('#span2').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus")

    //Add some code here to show the second group like so
    $('#collapseGroupTwo').toggleClass('collapse');
    //OR maybe just slide toggle instead? Depends how your css is with collapse class
    $('#collapseGroupTwo').stop(true, true).slideToggle(); 
})
```